# Is there a way to get translatable attributes of a model extended with Mobility gem?

Tags: ruby, mobility

Is there a way to get translatable attributes of a model extended with [Mobility](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility) gem?

I've got a parent -> child objects conversion. Parent and child are different models even though they have almost the same structure, so I can't just dup it. I'm passing most of the attributes using `Parent.attributes`, still Mobility methods like `name_en` etc is not among those.

So, if I have an object extended with Mobility and having `translates :name, translates :description`. Is there a method to call on Parent class or instance to get an array like `[:name, :description]` or `[:name_en, :name_de, :descroption_en, :description_de, ...]` or even a key-value hash?